# Why aren't my ads showing inside my android app?

Tags: android, admob, adsense

I just made my first 2d game and did everything the admob said to put my ads on and I Exported the .apk and copied it on my android phone to see if the ads were working but none of the ads show up? Do I have to upload it to play store it to work?

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have the right admob ID ,

and try to change your package name "com.package.something"
also see if test ads will appear in your app by adding

```
.addTestDevice("your_device_id_for_admob")
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally it will take up to 48 hours for the first ads to start showing up.
(Which is not a great design, it should show filler content, like the test ads, until actual ones come through)